# Admin UI to manage advanced search filter

Tags: gui-design, filter, administration, advancedsearch

I am working on an admin interface that manages a dropdown filter located on an advanced search screen that is available for all users.

The admins can exclude options in the Manufacture filter.  [See wireframes 1]

[image: default search]

If an option is excluded from a filter on the admin manage filter screen, this option will not show in the filter dropdown. A checkbox will appear under that filter. By unchecking it, users can bring the excluded option back to the filter dropdown. [See wireframes 2]

[image: Revised Filter]

The problem is how to inform admin users that if an option is unchecked, users will be able to view it by unchecking the checkbox?

Is there a better way to design the admin UI that will show the relationship between the options selected in the admin and the advanced search UI?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **more straightforward description** of the options as well as **using separate groups in Admin UI**:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIFeD.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Good answer and very nice solution. I think the Admin UI is alright with checkboxes too, just needs better wording.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right. I think that one possible solution would be adding a label to the checkboxes column saying "Tick the checkbox to make an option visible by default".